# Return Expressions in C++

Tags: c++, return, standards, return-value, code-standards

Consider the following code:

```
float validateEntry()
{
    string entry;
    float value;

    getline(cin, entry);
    value = atof(entry.data());

    return ((isNumber(entry) && value >= 0) ? i
    : (cout << "Enter valid amount: ", validateEntry())
}
```

Why is the last line (the comma-separated expression) allowed, and are there other expressions that can be used with return statements in C++?

I'm mostly confused at the use of the comma, and wondering where this expression syntax is defined (I had no idea it existed, nor would I have known where to find out). Can I fill that last expression with an indefinite amount of code; if so, what are the limitations, requirements, etc.?

Comment: Why do you think it should not be allowed ?

Comment: By the way the ternary operator `? :` is not a shorthand for `if`. `if` allows conditionally executing code (any code). The ternary operator **returns** one value between two according to a condition.

Comment: Sorry, a completely incorrect title, as I forgot to change it before posting.

Comment: @J.N.: If we're going to be pedantic, the ternary operator doesn't **return** anything. It *evaluates* to a *result*.

Comment: @user349433 : thanks for the precision. sunday: you should till tell us what's bothering you with that code. It will be hard to give any answers though.

Comment: IIRC `std::string::data()` does not null-terminate, which is going to cause you problems if you pass its result to `atof`.

Comment: `return` or no `return`, what you've got there is all a valid C++ expression.

Comment: @ephemient without a return, the function (which is intended to return a float) is pretty useless though, wouldn't you say?

Comment: Invalid, even.  What I meant was that the expression following the `return` is valid irrespective of the fact that it's part of a `return` statement.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit interestingly, the program runs fine with no errors. (?) atof will also return 0.0 if no conversion could be made. But maybe `c_str` should be used instead? Thoughts?

Comment: @Sunday: Invoking undefined behaviour is not required to cause an error any more than is it required _not_ to cause a black hole to open up inside your carefully-prepared evening meal. `c_str` is _definitely_ what you meant.

Comment: @Lightness FWIW, it didn't before, but it provides a null-terminated string in C++11.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Well, pre-11 didn't have `data`, anyway.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Huh? Sure it did (`[C++03: 23.3.6/3]`)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `data` behaves exactly like `c_str`. Both return a NUL-terminated string by standard.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Only as of C++11, as we all just discussed already. In C++98 and C++03, `std::string::data` and `std::string::c_str` had differing semantics.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just looked it up and it seems you're right, there was indeed a `data` in pre-11 (and it doesn't behave like `c_str`). I had never ever heard of this method or seen it used before C++11. Sorry for that.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Apology accepted :) You didn't need to look too hard, though; I cited chapter and verse for you!

Comment: Also, why would they introduce `std::string:data` in C++11, just to have the same semantics as a function in the same class that already exists? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma operator allows you to group two otherwise-unrelated expressions. Both expressions are always evaluated, and the result is the result of the second expression. It is almost always a bad idea to use it (because it hurts readability just to save a line of code), except maybe in the top of a for-loop.

Comment: Ah, the COMMA OPERATOR. It all makes sense now. I didn't quite know where my question was going at first, because I didn't know the operator existed. This led me to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/c-comma-operator

Answer (score 1):

```
return [expression];

expression :
   expression , expression
   literal
   etc...
```

The comma operator separates multiple expressions on a single line. When used in an assignment statement like the return statement (assigning a temporary value which is returned), only the rightmost value is assigned. The preceding expressions are executed from left to right. In your example, the final function call returned value is returned.

I use this technique to clear formal argument variables on failure. Especially COM routines where there is a failure. For example:

```
HRESULT func(..., IInterface **ppv)
{
...
If(!good)
  return (*ppv = 0), E_FAIL;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`,` is an operator just like `+` or `<<` so you can use it freely almost wherever an expression is expected. Exceptions are contexts where a comma is expected with a different meaning, such as in a function call. In such contexts you have to disambiguate the comma by adding an extra set of parens:

```
foo((b,c)); // call foo with a single argument
```

The statement you show is the equivalent of:

```
// return ((isNumber(entry) && value >= 0) ? i : (cout << "Enter valid amount: ", validateEntry())

if(isNumber(entry) && value >= 0) {
    return i;
} else {
    cout << "Enter valid amount: ";
    return validateEntry();
}
```

It's just a 'clever' way of conditionally executing the `cout << "Enter valid amount: "` before calling `validateEntry()` while using as few lines as possible. Of course the whole function is just a 'clever' way to repeatedly ask for an input until it gets valid input. IMO a loop would be better than recursion here.

Answer (score 0):

`? :` is the only ternary opeartor of C++

its syntax is `logical-or-expression ? expression : conditional-expression`

You can read more about it at  [MSDN](http://%5Bhttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx%5D)